# MongoDB C# CommandDocument how to add query

Tags: c#, mongodb

If the command in the shell is:

```
db.runCommand({"distinct":"log", "key":"cs_uri_stem"});
```

I figure out that the corresponding C# code is :

```
var command = new CommandDocument { 
                                            { "distinct", "log" }, 
                                            { "key", "cs_uri_stem"},
                                    };
```

But how about the following command?

```
db.runCommand({"distinct":"log", "key":"cs_uri_stem", query:{ datetime: { $gt: new ISODate("2012-07-05T19:55:18.475Z"), $lt:new ISODate("2012-07-05T20:55:18.475Z")} }})
```

I can't figure out how to do it in C#...

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also asked and answered at:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/mongodb-user/TKZj_Qs0W5E

There's actually a helper method in MongoCollection that you can use. Your second distinct command could be coded in C# like this:

```
var collection = database.GetCollection("log");
var query = Query.And(
    Query.GT("datetime", new DateTime(2012, 7, 5, 19, 55, 18, 475, DateTimeKind.Utc)),
    Query.LT("datetime", new DateTime(2012, 7, 5, 20, 55, 18, 475, DateTimeKind.Utc))
);
var result = collection.Distinct("cs_uri_stem", query);
foreach (var distinctValue in result)
{
    // process distinctValue
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        Query.And(Query.GT("datetime", DateTime.UtcNow), Query.LT("datetime", DateTime.UtcNow));
```